# Tail bounds for a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Assume $(X,Y) \sim \mathcal{N}_{2}(\mu, \Sigma)$ is a bivariate normal random vector. Given $s>0$, I am trying to find
$$P(X < 0 \; \land \; Y > s)$$ or at least get a close bound for it.
Obviously I could just compute the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{s}^{\infty} \phi(x,y) dy dx$$
but I don't see how that leads to a closed form expression.

Comment: It might help you, both computationally and conceptually, to make an affine change of variable to reformulate the event as $\Pr(|Y| \le \lambda(s) X\wedge X \gt 0)$ (for a simple expression $\lambda$). It would be interesting (and straightforward) to compare the latter to a tail bound for $X$ itself.